# Why is Google Maps showing Google Search?

Tags: javascript, google-search, google-maps

When we disable Javascript and visit [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com), it shows the page for Google Search instead:

[image]

I'm getting this behavior regardless of the browser used (Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Opera).

What's going on?

Is this a bug with Google?

Comment: What did you expect Google Maps to do without javascript?

Comment: @Zoredache, Perhaps an error message. Or anything instead of showing a broken Google **Search** page.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the case for me. It doesnot show you that page even with the JavaScript turned off.

Here is what I got,

[image]

You can see, if the JS is turned off. The Site would load with just a page and no content. Because all the content is loaded using Ajax requests. Which requires you to enable JavaScript.

If you don't. It won't show you any thing at all. My Browser was: Google Chrome v35.0.1916.86 beta-m

Also, check that I had JS turned off, see in the URL bar to the right side, the third-first icon with red mark says: 'JavaScript was turned off for this page'.

It loaded the page, but didn't load content, because it wasn't able to do so.

Although yes, you're right Google must do something related to this. It must show an alert box saying something like this

> Please enable JavaScript in your browser for us to load the Data.

Comment: `That's not true.` seems pretty aggressive. It doesn't really matter but maybe you should say `That's  not the case for me` because google *heavily* changes things based on location and does a **lot** of A/B testing. You guys might be in different groups.

Comment: @chipperyman573, I think you're right. I really did write aggressive words, although I wasn't angry at him at all :D But, I removed them if they were some sort of hate speech :)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan, Odd, couldn't get your behavior no matter what I do.

Comment: Actually, what I was trying to say was, JavaScript is required to load the Ajax data. If JS is turned off, then Data won't load up. But still it won't redirect me to the Google Homepage